# GUI Ubuntu stuck_1

Tags: gui, ubuntu-gnome, malware, display-manager

I deployed several years ago open free software [Dspace 6 repository](https://dspace.lyrasis.org/download/) [docs](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/DSpace+6.x+Documentation) on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS desktop.

I deployed Dspace on http, not on https. 1,5 years ago There was situation when The virus (https://medium.com/@ankurjoshissj/what-is-watchbog-and-how-to-remove-it-common-steps-for-removing-malware-from-linux-systems-836e8128bb81 ) penetrated in my Ubuntu. There is a serious reason why the postgresql database backup was not made in time and I did not to fix https. Now I have problem with my Ubuntu. Maybe it is new virus which penetrated through Dspace http. The problem is that GUI Ubuntu stuck (Gnome Ubuntu stuck).

[image: GnomeNotLoading]

Also I can press ctrl+C and see the following text:

[image: Terminal1]

[image: Terminal2]

And I can press Alt+F2 and run tty2 where I can see error string “I have no name!@repository”:

[image: tty2]

I read everything in the Internet conserning this problem and I could not resolve this problem. Would you have such possibility to help me? I lack for knowledge to solve my problem.

I need to avoid the situation when I need to reinstall Ubuntu, because 1.5 years have passed since the last backup of my repository database was made. I can lose lots of users data. And now I can not to make backup because I have the following error: “[archiver (db)] connection to database “dspace” failed: local user with ID 122 does not exists”.

[image: BackUp_Dspace]

Continuation of these post:
[GUI Ubuntu stuck_2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477611/gui-ubuntu-stuck-2)

Comment: Any system administrator or serious user should know not to wait ~1.5 years to take down a system infected with a virus, and reinstall. Not having a backup is also a major misstep. I don't think this is solvable, you must wipe it clean and reinstall.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: FYI:  Your provided details (*if accurate*) show you've not applied security fixes since mid-late 2021 (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ for ISO release of 18.04.6, but note installed systems upgraded before that date)

Comment: You might have a change to check what happened if you execute `journalctl` or - if available - check your systemlog. (/var/log/syslog). But this "I have no name" indicates the loss of your home directory. Either through faulty disk or deliberate removal. Try to save your data and install a new Ubuntu (22.04)

Comment: Your provided details show a system that stopped being maintained in 2021; which as I understand it was before Russia invaded Ukraine; and 22 & 22.04 are different products (22 being a *flavor* of 22.04 LTS Server released a few months later, you can't upgrade from a *deb* based system to a *snap* only system)

Comment: @Maiia Much as I support Ukraine's effort to stay free and independent, there is no magic solution to every Ubuntu problem. You need to backup user data, and reinstall.

Comment: Couple of quick thoughts - there's obvious compromise, and obviously broken accounts, so its probably worth thinking about 'do I want to do this quick and risk more issues' or 'do I want to do it right?' Do you have hardware to 'test' and stage your fixes? You might want to try, for example (AFTER backing up the system), reinstalling. postgres to see if it fixes the missing account (since postgres will likely set it up again), but this might mean tweaking the repos since they might be down. Also after a few years, people forget stuff, so... do you have any documentation of what you did?

Comment: looks like you lost user "postres" in the password file. Try `sudo adduser --system --home /var/lib/postgresql --shell /bin/bash --no-create-home --ingroup postgres --uid 122  postgres`

Comment: I have user "postgres" in /etc/passwd: 
postgres:x:122:127:PostgreSQl administrator,,,:var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

1. Load a recent Ubuntu off a USB stick in a Try mode
2. Make a back up of user data into an external drive
3. Reinstall the system
4. Restore the backup